# Integrate microcontroller with 3G dongle

Tags: 3g, dongle

I want to **`integrate`** a Luminary microcontroller with a **`3G USB`** dongle.

Do all USB dongles support **`AT commands`**?

If not then what is the **`best`** way to do it?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to plug the 3G modem into the Luminary microcontroller?

Comment: yes plug 3G modem to USB socket, yet no plan to put RTOS on my microcontroller

Comment: What is the OS on the microcontroller?

Comment: Integrating without an OS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can expect that the 3G dongle will support AT commands.  You need the modem (dongle) to make a modem port available, to which you can send AT commands.  For this, you need a suitable driver, and maybe some software to convert the dongle from a USB mass storage device to a modem, depending upon your device.  (When you first plug the modem in, it may be seen as a mass storage device, and must be converted to a modem)
Ask the manufacturer for details, as this is not a standard procedure, and implementation is manufacturer specific.

Comment: Can u please elaborate what is the process or commands to convert mass storage device to modem, as there is no OS so can;t work on drivers.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer for details, as converting from mass storage to modem is not a standard procedure, and implementation is different for each manufacturer.  Sorry, a microcontroller without OS is beyond my experience.